# Always getting this AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 302 (expected 200)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tdd

I'm very new in django, and currently was following a tutorial and I was trying to test users are listed on user page. So I setup test_admin.py. And i get an AssertionError 302 != 200.

Below are my test_admin.py

```
from django.test import TestCase,Client
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse


class AdminSiteTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.admin_user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
            email='admin@gmail.com',
            password='092100027h'
        )
        self.client.force_login(self.admin_user)
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email='test@gmail.com',
            password='092100027h',
            name='Test User Full Name'
        )

    def test_users_listed(self):
        """
        Test that users are listed on user page
        """
        url = reverse('admin:core_user_changelist')
        res = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertContains(res, self.user.name)
        self.assertContains(res, self.user.email)
```

and this is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from . import models

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display = ['email', 'name']


admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

and this is my error

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_users_listed (core.tests.test_admin.AdminSiteTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/core/tests/test_admin.py", line 28, in test_users_listed
    self.assertContains(res, self.user.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 446, in assertContains
    response, text, status_code, msg_prefix, html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 418, in _assert_contains
    " (expected %d)" % (response.status_code, status_code)
AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 302 (expected 200)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.795s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be related to `APPEND_SLASH` Django setting. By default its `True`. So check your urls file and make sure this url ends with slash `/` (like `articles/<int:year>/` or otherwise Django won't find the url and will automatically add slash and redirects you to a new url and you will receive `302` status code as redirect.

Comment: if you would like to see the code here is the repo https://github.com/metalheadcode/recipe-app-api, anyway im using docker

Answer (score 2):

it's my fault, I accidently set my is_active default into False, it should be like this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that support using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) <<< This one
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: This helped, merci :)

Comment: glad to hear it :)